# how to subtract/not consider a Date Range

Tags: formula-field, date

I have field called CBN__c on child object Score and i need to rollup this to the parent account based on Approved Scores. I did create a batch class that updates Account's CBN field but i got a new requirement to not consider/subtract any child CBNs that have Live__date__c between 12/15 and 02/15 of any given years. So i have this formula field on child but how to generalize this without having to subtract year wise.

```
IF((Live_Date__c >= DATE(2020,12,15) && Live_Date__c <= DATE(2021,2,15))||(Live_Date__c >= DATE(2021,12,15) && Live_Date__c <= DATE(2022,2,15))||(Live_Date__c >= DATE(2022,12,15) && Live_Date__c <= DATE(2023,2,15)), 0 ,IF(ISPICKVAL(Score_Status__c,"Approved"),CBN__c,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use functions `MONTH` and `DAY` in the formula, to check whether `Live_Date__c` month and day matches the criteria you are looking for.

In this way, you can keep it generic irrespective of the year in the date.

This formula returns true if `Live_Date__c` falls between 12/15 and 02/15, this can help you to proceed further :

```
(MONTH( Live_Date__c) = 12 && DAY( Live_Date__c) > 15) ||
( MONTH( Live_Date__c) < 2 || ( MONTH( Live_Date__c) = 2 && DAY( Live_Date__c) < 15 ))
```

More info here:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions.htm&type=5
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.formula_examples_dates.htm&type=5